# How to print compass orientation on Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-location, compass-geolocation

I am very new to coding in general and have been following lots of tutorials to get where I am right now. I followed this other question of stackoverflow: [Finding the compass orientation of an iPhone in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30704823/finding-the-compass-orientation-of-an-iphone-in-swift)

Following the code in each answer, nothing is being printed. This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class PointingViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
}

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        print(newHeading.magneticHeading)
    }

   @IBAction func firstButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
}
```

Ideally, the compass orientation is recorded whenever the button is pressed. I have tried putting the `.startUpdatingLocation()` and `.startUpdatingHeading` in the `viewDidLoad()` function, but no change occurs.

Is there a better way to accomplish what I desire?

Answer (score 0):

Code looks alright apart from you not doing all the things the documentation says you need to do, like check `isHeadingAvailable` etc. Docs say:

If heading information is not supported, calling this method has no effect and does not result in the delivery of events to your delegate.

Implement `locationManager(_:didFailWithError:)` is also a good plan if things aren't working.

Have you done the necessary things regarding Location permissions documented in "Adding Location Services to Your App"

Answer (score 0):

You should search for a proper tutorial for this online. I will give you some pointers to get you started, but please do your own research.
You have to request permission first. Add this to your `viewDidLoad`

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

Also implement the delegate method

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    // start requesting heading information if you are authorized. 
}
```

And deal with the different states.

Also you may need to add a permission entry in your Info.plist, but I am not sure it is required for heading.